# Executing the Unix script from Java

Tags: java, bash, unix

I am trying to run a unix shell script from java which is available at a particular directory in unix server. This script accepts parameters. I was able to establish SFTP connection and successfully reached to the directory which is  holding the shell script. How do i run this script and how to pass parameters? Got few references at https://netjs.blogspot.com/2016/10/how-to-run-shell-script-from-java-program.html
 but here the script is available at local system. In my case the script is on server and also accepts parameters.

Comment: How does your java application establish that connection? What library are you using?

Comment: Use [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) to connect to your server via SSH and get a shell to execute commands on the server. See here for a [code example](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/): [Shell.java](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Shell.java.html).

Answer (score 3):

`SFTP` is a file transfer protocol (`Secure File Transfer Protocol`). It lets you transfer the files to and from the server. However, it **doesn't** let you execute any script on the remote server as that's not what it's designed to do.

If you want to execute a script in remote server then you need to:

- Establish an `ssh` connection
- Execute the script from that connection

You need to use a library like `JSch`, [here's](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Exec.java.html) an example.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is execute command over SSH. 
You create a new script in your localhost (my sample is `test.sh`) with content as below, and now you can execute it like the way you get from your references.

`ssh user@server "sh your-shell-script-in-server.sh"`

Read more at
https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-execute-command-using-ssh/

Java source:

```
    String[] cmd = new String[] { "/bin/sh", "test.sh" };
    try {
        Process pr = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
        int rs = pr.waitFor();
    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Java function is based on the `Runtime` object. I'm not sure but I think you can't get the `Runtime` object of a remote machine, therefore you'll need to put the CLASS-file on that remote machine and launch it up there.